# ASP.NET Storing shopcart data in a session

Tags: asp.net

Hey how to store shopcart data in a session variables

I.e. for each product added to the cart I have i.e.

ProductId
Quantity

But then how can I store multiple records of this in a session.

I.e. I am used to just going session["username"] = "Bob".

1) So how can I store this multiple row data in session
2) How to add the individual records to the session
3) How to loop through the session data

Comment: I think you can get answers for the following link where you can type your query and get results Link: http://www.google.co.in. just type "shopping cart in asp.net" and you will get better codes as well as better solutions

Answer (score 2):

`Session` can store any `object`, so you can either save list of products using `ArrayList` or can make and save custom class object...

e.g.

```
public class ShoppingCart {
public String User {get; set;}
public List<Product> CartItems{ get; set;}
}

public class Product {
public int ProductId {get; set;}
public int Qty {get; set;}
}
```

and then save it like this:

```
ShoppingCart c = new ShoppingCart();
...
Session["Cart"] = c;
```

and

```
ShoppingCart c = (ShoppingCart) Session["Cart"];
```

Hope this helps...